# How to display user input variables in single quotes in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to display user input data in single quotes, but something seems to be going wrong. Can you please help.

For eg:

```
name1 = raw_input()
print "[{0}]". format ("'"+ "','".join (str(i) for i in [name1] + "'")
```

However it's working as below:

```
Input-
Jan, Feb
Actual output- ['Jan,Feb']
Expected output- ['Jan','Feb']
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: This smells a bit like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). What are you **really** trying to achieve here? Why do you need the output to be in that format?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the user input to a list, why not, [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it?

```
name1 = raw_input()
# input Jan, Feb
print name1.split(',')
# output ['Jan', ' Feb']
```

Note that this outputs `['Jan', ' Feb']` so you probably want to use `.strip` as well, *or* use `', '` as the split token.

```
name1 = raw_input()
# input Jan, Feb
print name1.split(', ')
# output ['Jan', 'Feb']
```

Comment: Since it seems like he wants that as str, he could probably just do `print(str(name1.split(',')))`. Or even a `repr` won't hurt.

Comment: @WiggyA. I'm not entirely convinced OP *actually* wants the output as `str`. What would be the usage of a list-string literal? I suppose only the OP can answer that.

Comment: I literally have no idea. Just trying to make sense of his current code. Worst case scenario, his goal is to actually serve that list as json.

Comment: I am trying to user input 2 sets of values and then trying to determine if a string in one of the user input data overlaps in another user input data.
I want to display the user input in above mentioned format.
For eg:
User input-
Inp1 - Jan,Feb
Inp2 - Mar, Apr
Expected output-
['Jan','Feb']
['Mar','Apr']
Non overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Would the unholy use of print and repr help here?

```
>>> name1 = input()
[1, 2, '3', 'four']
>>> print(repr(name1))
"[1, 2, '3', 'four']"
```